# Difference between jframe.add() and jframe.getcontentpane().add()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, contentpane

I want know difference between fallowing code

```
Jframe myframe= new Jframe();
myframe.add(new jbutton());
```

And

```
Contentpane cp=Myframe.getcontentpane();
```

cup.add(new jbutton());